# NSAttributeString - How to remove auto formatting for a date or time item?

Tags: objective-c, formatting, nsdate, nsattributedstring

With NSAttributeString, it auto creates formatting and clickable events for date or time elements within that NSAttributeString

But what I'd like to do is remove the date handling, and its formatting from the NSAttributedString and handle the formatting so its my own format and not clickable.

Is there a way to switch it off?

Many thanks

Picture added

[image: date had a link]

Comment: What creates this date/time formatting?

Comment: Its a time stamp. Or a date object inside the NSAttributeString

Comment: So what does the actual formatting?  You seem to imply the `NSAttributedString` object does it itself.

Comment: Added image.  When I put a breakpoint on the creation of the attributedstring it does not state the link coloring or activity;  `
{
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7f82094db000> font-family: \"Avenir-Roman\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14.00pt";
}
`

Comment: Well before you can switch it off, you need to understand what's doing it.  It's certainly not `NSAttributedString` "auto formatting it", however.

Comment: I am using the JSQMessage podfile; so I will try to investigate if this is cauisng it

Comment: I believe it is related to UIDataDetectorType

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to set the dataDetectorTypes to none and this fixed the issue.

`[cell.textView setDataDetectorTypes:UIDataDetectorTypeNone];`